# Java installation in Ubuntu for topcoder

Tags: 13.04, java

Can someone help me with an issue?
I want to do TopCoder﻿. It needs a Java applet.
I'm new to ubuntu, have the 13.04 version and have no idea how to get **Java installed and which version of it** should I get for the applet? Please suggest what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest to uninstall any existing version of openjdk-java or jre, or icedtea-plugin from your machine.

Next, download jre or jdk 1.7 provided by oracle, if you want to use the topcoder arena without any issues in ubuntu.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Download the tar.gz archive (source) and build it using the instructions given in the readme file.

It helped me, hope it works for you too.
If any issues, let me know.